# How to align horizontally and vertically to a fixed positioned div?

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="someid">some text here</div>
```

css...

```
#someid{position: fixed; width: 500px; height: 30px;}
```

I want to position absolutely center to horizontal and vertical to window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#someid{
position: 
fixed; 
width: 500px; 
height: 30px; 
right:50%; 
margin-right:-250px;
}
```

The negative margin is to fix the offset that occurs when the browser will consider the div's right side to be 50% from the right of the browser window.

To center it vertically, you may want to try the same thing (no guarantees here though as I haven't done this before) with its vertical position.

For example:

```
top:50%;
margin-top:-15px;
```

*Edit*
A little more thorough explanation: When #someid is placed 50% from the right it is positioned so that it is 50% of its parent's total width away from the parent's right border. This however, doesn't measure from the center of #someid to the right border of its parent element, it measures from the right side of #someid to the right side of its parent element. This of course, doesn't quite center #someid, it's still offset by half of its width.

This is why we use a negative margin to offset it. The negative margin needs to be half of #someid's width to make up for the offset to the left that occures when we place it by it's right side 50% from the right of its parent element.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your comment. What's the status? Is it working? Horizontal should definitely work, but I'm not positive on vertical.

Comment: Yes! Its perfectly working on all browsers (old also). But I din't know how left: 25%; works? Please comment about this.

Comment: @C-Link You mean 50%? I've updated my answer with a little more thorough explanation. If that doesn't quite explain it I would just look up `position:left;` and margins on w3schools.com.

Comment: @user1803405- No! Your method works. But I'm saying what my answer is also working but how left:25%; work?

Answer (score 0):

While your position is `fixed` you cannot position the div relatively. You must calculate the top and left values by javascript. You can center its position horizontally by writing this:

```
width: #SOMEWIDTH#px;
margin: 0 auto;
```

To make the margin position the div at the center the width attribute MUST be set.
Auto margining does not affect vertical postiion.